# Update a value from child class to parent class in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make different HP for different enemies where I want to change the value of a child class by calling a function from it's parent class. So in this way I can simply use the parent class functions but HP will be different for different types of enemies. I'm new to Unity so not sure how to do that.

Here are my codes:

**Enemy.cs (Parent)**

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hp = 30;  // Need to get this value from Child class
    protected Animator anm;
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;

    protected virtual void Start() {
        anm = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Hurt() {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        anm.SetTrigger("hurt");
        hp -= 10;
        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    public void Death() {
        anm.SetTrigger("death");
    }
}
```

**Guard.cs (Child)**

```
public class Guard : Enemy
{
    public int hp = 50;
    protected Animator anm;
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        coll = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }
}
```

How can I make the `hp` value different for different enemies in Unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't [hide](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) `hp` (and others fields/properties) from base class to derived ones.

They are already within the parent class and therefore present in the derived

In `Start()`, you can add `hp = 50;`

**Enemy.cs (Parent)**

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int hp = 30;  // Need to get this value from Child class
    protected Animator anm;
    protected Rigidbody2D rb;

    protected virtual void Start() {
        anm = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Hurt() {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        anm.SetTrigger("hurt");
        hp -= 10;
        if (hp <= 0)
        {
            Death();
        }
    }

    public void Death() {
        anm.SetTrigger("death");
    }
}
```

**Guard.cs (Child)**

```
public class Guard : Enemy
{
    // remove the fields/properties already present in Enemy

    protected override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        hp = 50; // <-------------------       Set the value for Guard here
        coll = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. You're right for removing fields/properties already present in Enemy, I actually did that in my actual script, forgot to remove here. So now, if I create another child class of `Enemy` & if I want that one's hp to be 100 then I'll just change it on `Start()`? Will doing this affect the other child class?

Comment: Nope, it won't affect other child. Imagine you have a child, it inherits some stuff from you (genetics). One day, your child decide to have green hair. Will all your child have green hair? The only case it could affect all derived class would be if you change something `static`